# Remove duplicates from rows of a csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, repeat, duplicates

I'm new to Python and trying to do the following. 
I have a csv file like below, (input.csv)

```
a,v,s,f
china,usa,china and uk,france
india,australia,usa,uk
japan,south africa,japan,new zealand
```

where I'd like to remove duplicates with respect to each row to get the below.

```
a,v,s,f (output.csv)
china,usa, and uk,france
india,australia,usa,uk
japan,south africa,,new zealand
```

Notice that though 'usa' is repeated in two different rows, it still is kept intact, unlike 'china' and 'japan', which are repeated in same rows.

I tried doing using OrderedDict from collections in the following way

```
from collections import OrderedDict
out = open ("output.csv","w")
items = open("input.csv").readlines()
print >> out, list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items))
```

but it moved all the data into one single row

Comment: readlines() is going to read all of the lines from the file when used with no argument. probably should use readline() instead to read one line at a time, and do that for each line until you are done.

Comment: @JamesH Thank you for the response. By `do that for each line until you are done`, do you mean that I should rerun the script manually for each line?

Comment: Look at ray.dino's answer. That's a great solution that actually works fine with readlines() but does logically the same thing that I was getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we might hurt the dataset while iterating rows and deleting items without caring the related original position. There is related index (Column/Rows) to every item, deleting it can move the next items to other position.

Try to use [pandas](http://synesthesiam.com/posts/an-introduction-to-pandas.html) in such scenarios. by selecting items in the same row, you can apply a function to re-construct the row respecting their position. We use `in` operator to deal with such scenarios `china and uk`, and we replace the duplicated values with a an empty str.

```
 def trans(x):
        d=[y for y in x]
        i=0
        while i<len(d):
            j=i+1
            item=d[i]
            while j<len(d):
                if item in d[j]: 
                    d[j]=d[j].replace(item,'')
                j+=1
            i+=1
        return d
```

Your code would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data="""a,v,s,f
china,usa,china and uk,france
india,australia,usa,uk
japan,south africa,japan,new zealand"""
df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(data.decode('UTF-8')) )


from collections import Counter
def trans(x):
    d=[y for y in x]
    i=0
    while i<len(d):
        j=i+1
        item=d[i]
        while j<len(d):
            if item in d[j]: 
                d[j]=d[j].replace(item,'')
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return d

print df.apply(lambda x:trans(x),axis=1 )


       a             v        s            f
0  china           usa   and uk       france
1  india     australia      usa           uk
2  japan  south africa           new zealand
```

In order to read your csv file, you just need to replace the name. [More details should be found here](http://synesthesiam.com/posts/an-introduction-to-pandas.html)

```
 df= pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be asked more specifically as, "How to remove duplicate items from lists." For which there's an existing solution: [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists)

So, assuming that your CSV file looks like this:
**items.csv**

```
a,v,s,f
china,usa,china,uk,france
india,australia,usa,uk
japan,south africa,japan,new zealand
```

I intentionally changed "china and uk" in line 2 to "china,uk". Note below.

Then the script to remove duplicates could be:

```
import sys
with open('items.csv', 'r') as csv:
    for line in csv.readlines():
        print list(set(line.split(',')))
```

Note: Now, if the 2nd really does contain "china and uk", you'd have to do something different than processing the file as a CSV.

Comment: Good clean "Python-ey" solution

Comment: You might face problems in cases such : "china,usa,china and uk,france" + when u use set, r reduce the position. which means that you r moving them to different columns to make the last one emty.